# i read the k-d tree Pseudocode and do not know the meanig of this line

Tags: c

```
function kdtree (list of points pointList, int depth)
{
    // Select axis based on depth so that axis cycles through all valid values
    var int axis := depth mod k;

    // Sort point list and choose median as pivot element
    select median by axis from pointList;

    // Create node and construct subtrees
    var tree_node node;
    node.location := median;
    node.leftChild := kdtree(points in pointList before median, depth+1);
    node.rightChild := kdtree(points in pointList after median, depth+1);
    return node;
}
```

anyone could help me to explain the line "var int axis := depth mod k;",

why mod k, k is what?

Comment: Do you know what [*mod*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) is?

Comment: This is not valid `C` code. The notation `function x` is not C, nor is `var int x`, nor is `:=`. Perhaps that is why you were unable to find an explanation using Google.

Comment: This is not a valid code. This is pseudocode from wikipedia page for kdtree. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`k` is the dimension of the tree. You will have to repeatedly divide the set of points along each direction one by one.
Here `depth` represents the level of a tree. Now as you go down each level, you have to move to next axis, and when you are done with the last axis (i.e. kth dimension) you will start again from 1st dimension (or in this case, from (k-1) to 0th dimension). Hence the next axis is chosen as `depth mod k`

Answer (score 1):

k is a number of dimensions. Variable axis will contain an axis along which the space will be divided.